# Get indexOf of an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array that looks like this

```
data: Array(3)
  0:
      data: Object
      account_id: (...)
      address_1: (...)
      address_2: (...)
      amount: 10.00
      id: 1234
...
 1:
      data: Object
      account_id: (...)
      address_1: (...)
      address_2: (...)
      amount: 20.00
      id: 1274
```

I am making an axios call to get data of a particular item clicked and show it in a modal so i have this

```
<div v-for="card in card_data" v-bind:key="card.data.id">
...
 <a  class="text-white shadow" @click="cardClicked(card.data.id)"> Card details</a>
 </div>
```

```
export default {

  
   data() {
        return {
           
          },
            name_on_card:'',
            card_pan:'',
            expiration:'',
            cvv:'',
            request_data: [],
            
        }
    },
cardClicked: function(id) {
              axios.get('api/get_vcard').then(response => {
             let i = this.request_data.map(item => item.data.id).indexOf(id);
            this.name_on_card = response.data[i].name_on_card;
          this.card_pan = response.data[i].data.card_pan;
          this.expiration= response.data[i].data.expiration;
          
            }).catch(error => console.log(error)); 
        },
}
```

When i click on the button it does not pull up the data

but when i try this for one of the entry it works and pulls the data

```
this.name_on_card = response.data[i].name_on_card;
```

How can i map this correctly to get the index of a clicked item and show the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this.request_data` doesn't make much sense since you want to loop over the **response** that you get from axios, hence you should use it, extrapolate the values and in the end get the index for a specific value

```
cardClicked: function(id) {
  axios.get('api/get_vcard').then(response => {
    let i = response.data.map(item => item.data.id).indexOf(id);
        
    this.name_on_card = response.data[i].name_on_card;
    this.card_pan = response.data[i].card_pan;
    this.expiration = response.data[i].expiration;

  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
},
```

Comment: Note that an even easier way would be `.findIndex(item => item.data.id === id)` instead of `.map(item => item.data.id).indexOf(id)`

Comment: @CherryDT Agree with you.

Comment: @CherryDT ofcourse, following just OPs way of doing it... cheers

Comment: I don't know if it is a problem now with accessing the ````id```` but i am getting ````TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined```` error message

Comment: I realize, here a `find` would make even more sense. (as improvement to the OP)

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, unfortunately you didn't show the content of `response.data`. Anyway supposing that `response.data` contains an id, your `map` is correct. I made an example:

```js
let responseWithIdInData = [{data: {
          account_id: "(...)",
          address_1: "(...)",
          address_2: "(...)",
          amount: 10.00,
          id: 1234}},
          {data: {
          account_id: "(...)",
          address_1: "(...)",
          address_2: "(...)",
          amount: 20.00,
          id: 1274},
          }];
          
let id = 1274;
let i = responseWithIdInData.map(item => item.data.id).indexOf(id);
console.log(i) // return 1 ok!
```

But I don't know if `responseWithIdInData` is like your data shape. Infact from your code seems more that your response is like this:

```
let responseWithIdOutsideData = [{data: { /*there is an id here??*/},
              account_id: (...),
              address_1: (...),
              address_2: (...),
              amount: 10.00,
              id: 1234},
              {data: {/*there is an id here??*/},
              account_id: (...),
              address_1: (...),
              address_2: (...),
              amount: 20.00,
              id: 1274}];
```

In this second case I don't know because if there isn't an id inside `data`, your `map` doesn't work.

But lets suppose that you want to take `data` using the external id. You could try to do something like this:

```js
let responseWithIdOutsideData = [{data: { /*there is an id here??*/},
                  account_id: "(...)",
                  address_1: "(...)",
                  address_2: "(...)",
                  amount: 10.00,
                  id: 1234},
                  {data: {/*there is an id here??*/},
                  account_id: "(...)",
                  address_1: "(...)",
                  address_2: "(...)",
                  amount: 20.00,
                  id: 1274}];
                  
let id = 1274;
let i = responseWithIdOutsideData.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id);
console.log(responseWithIdOutsideData[i].data);
```

Comment: Yeah,it works. I am just suppose to access it this way...   this.card_pan = response.data[1].data.card_pan

Comment: @KingsleyOsuji no problem. Happy to help you. The only thing I don't understand is why you set the other answer as correct... :(

Comment: that is because changing  this.request_data.map(...) to response.data.map(...) solved the main problem in my code. The rest was my mistake in reading the data properly which your answer helped me resolve. Wish i could mark both as correct.

Comment: Ok I understand. I made the correct choice. Have a nice day :)